# Get the item from a ReferenceField type in Sitecore JSS based on Langauge version

Tags: jss, multilingual, graphql

I am working on a multi-lingual site where the data source has multiple language versions. I want to retrieve the items of multilist based on the language parameter passed.

**Sitecore GraphQL query:**

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/content/Global/Components/Navigation/CarsMenu", language: "de-DE") {
    children {
      ... on CarMenu {
        title {
          value
        }
        category {
          targetItems {
            ... on CarMenuCategory {
              language {
                name
              }
              title {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sitecore GraphQL Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "children": [
        {
          "title": {
            "value": "Autos"
          },
          "category": {
            "targetItems": [
              {
                "language": {
                  **"name": "en"**
                },
                "title": {
                  "value": "SUVs"
                }
              },
              {
                "language": {
                  "name": "en"
                },
                "title": {
                  "value": "Sedans"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Issue:**`
Even though I passed the "de-DE" language, the multilist item is returning the fall back "en" in response even though there is a "de-DE" version exists.

So, my question is how to get the target items based on the language version?

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this is to set the Sitecore Context Language to de-DE for the GraphQL query. Just add `&sc_lang=de-DE` to the querystring of the URL from the GraphQL endpoint. An now you can also remove the language in your query. And in the result al items are in "de-DE" or the version that you provide in the sc_lang parameter.

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/content/Global/Components/Navigation/CarsMenu") {
    children {
      ... on CarMenu {
        title {
          value
        }
        category {
          targetItems {
            ... on CarMenuCategory {
              language {
                name
              }
              title {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```